# Странное поведение базы данных MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Если я выполняю запрос на сервере(ubuntu 16.04) через консоль в mysql

```
SELECT * FROM mail_tab WHERE mid=428;
```

я получаю вот такой результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я когда я выполняю тот же запрос на php

```
function gmail($dat){
    global $db;
    $cm = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM mail_tab WHERE mid='".$dat[2]."'");
    $rcm = mysqli_fetch_row($cm);
    return $rcm;
}
```

и делаю var_dump($rcm);

Я вижу вот это.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите 5-й элемент массива (поле mbody в таблицы) пропал. Точнее представляет из себя строку с пробелами вместо данных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это такое? первый раз сталкиваюсь с подобным. Драйвер БД MariaDB

Comment: А вы его в браузер выводите ? он же интерпретирует `<p><img>`... Посмотрите в браузере исходный код страницы

Comment: А теперь добавьте в пятый столбец `<script>alert("XSS!")</script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return htmlspecialchars($rcm);
```